# SharePoint 2010 SPD Workflow copy list item to new list and designate the content type

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a functioning SPD workflow that copies the list item from list A to list B when the item in list A is marked approved.

My challenge is that list B has three content types to chose from. How do I designate which content type in list B to use when copying. I have a listbox that the user gets to choose what kind of a tool is being loaded. Some tools have required calibration dates and other tool specific items therefore the different content types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can specify the content type with Copy List Item - it should default to the default content type.

What I'd do instead is have my workflow Create List Item in List B, populating fields with values from Current Item. You can set Content Type ID by this process but it doesn't accept a variable, so use an If/Then block for each Tool type that only runs if that listbox value is selected.

Hope this helps!